# how do you check if something is directly infront, beside or behind you in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I've created a basic game, the first level is similar to minesweeper. I have a class for the mines which are randomly placed and a class for the player's character. I have set up collision detection between the player and the mines, what I would also like to do is to check what mines are directly beside the player, so I basically want to set up a what if scenario where it checks whether there would be a collision, if the player moved in any direction.

```cs
private void collisionTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(Jet j in jet)
    {
        foreach(Mines m in mine)
        {
            if (j.e.Bounds.IntersectsWith(m.m.Bounds))
            {
                gameOver();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That's the code I've used to detect collision between the player and mines, but I'm at a loss on how to set up potential collisions. Any help or nudges in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Something smells really bad, is your move code apart from the collision detection?

Comment: its under keydown event atm, should i have combined the 2?

Comment: Yep, suppose that I press the keys faster than the Tick of the timer, you may miss collisssions. Also, for your "what if" scenario you need to check for collision *before* it moves, you check if it *will* collide, if it will do kill the player (if that's what it should) else move it.

Comment: ok will combine them now, i already have the kill player part in there if it collides with a mine, what i want to do is be able to check around that player for any mines and display it in a label as say bombs 2 , i want to basically check for bombs directly in front without actuallu moving the player

Comment: Copy the bounds of the player object, displace it what it would move and check for intersections, that will tell you which mines would collide in the next movement.

Comment: ok thanks will have a look into that

Comment: WinForms isn't really the best thing to use to develop a graphical game, tbh. It's designed for line-of-business data entry and so on. Have you though of using Unity for example (assuming you'd want to stay in the .NET world)?

Comment: im on a college course and this is what they use so i have to do it in this im afraid

Comment: Are the placement of all the objects completely free form?...or do they exist in neat grids where things jump between positions and everything fits within one grid space?

Comment: im not 100% sure what you mean sorry? the mines are placed randomly on a panel between 20 and 380

Comment: "im on a college course and this is what they use"...if your college is teaching you to develop games using WinForms then I'd be tempted to find a new college! Or did you just decide to make a game yourself, instead of something more conventional?

Comment: So you're not representing the mines separately in a 2D array, for instance?

Comment: The mines are a class which are then put into a list and created on the panel when the form loads. This was what the college assignment was they showed a how it set up minesweeper type very basic game and you have to improve and add to it

Comment: So Gusman's comment way back at the top sounds like it makes sense for your setup.  Make a new, temporary [Rectangle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rectangle.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_Drawing_Rectangle__ctor_System_Drawing_Point_System_Drawing_Size_) that represents where the player will move to, then see if that  intersects with any of the mines.  For instance, if you're moving to the right, then you'd add some positive value to the the current X position, keeping the same Y and Width/Height.  Moving to the left, you'd decrease the X position, etc...

Comment: Ok will try that out tomorrow see if I can get it to work